# Was the Golden Army truly indestructible?

Tags: movie, hellboy

In *Hellboy 2: The Golden Army* a central device of the plot is a magical golden army with mechanical soldiers that are said to be indestructible. Indeed, this is put the test towards the end of the film, when Hellboy and crew fight a small number of the soldiers. Although Hellboy's team won their small fights, the battle remained undecided as the soldiers repaired themselves after a short delay.

This begs the question then, on what it would take to obliterate one of the soldiers such that it would be unable to repair and rejoin the fight. Would Liz Sherman be able to melt them into slag? Could Hellboy sufficiently demolish them such that they couldn't pull together again?

Ignoring the crown and the one wearing it, was there any way that these soldiers could have been permanently neutralized?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It depends. There is no canonical answer.**

Hellboy 2 was not based on any of the Hellboy Graphic Novels and therefore the canon can really only be based on what you see in the film. And since the film doesn't really explore what indestructible really means, we can't know for sure.

That said, there are a few possibilities. The self-reassembly nature of the army is clearly a hybrid of technological and magical means. Technologically speaking you should be able to separate the parts once they are split to neutralize the army. In practice this might be very difficult. Or impossible is their magical nature allows them to teleport.

They could be melted as you suggest, which would work great if the magic again can't step in to either prevent the melting or reassemble the army even from atoms.

So the question is, how likely is it that the army can teleport or resist heat? In the first case, it isn't shown and the fact that the parts roll and walk back to the soldier would suggest not. Heat wise, they seem to generate a lot and so it is likely that they are immune.

I'd say there is a very good chance that isolating the parts would immobilize the soldiers, assuming they couldn't break down whatever is doing that isolation. They weren't able to slice through anything and everything so it is likely that they couldn't escape from certain situations. The entire army being encased in concrete for example.

Answer (score 5):

### Their creator believed they could "never be stopped."

The mythical origin of the the army is given in both the film and a one-shot comic.

[image]

In both depictions, the story is an in-universe tale of unknown veracity. However, it tells of the elven king, his son and daughter, the army, and the crown that control it and those all turn out to be real, so perhaps it's all true. If this is the case, then the army's designer at least believed it to be truly unstoppable. Note that he existed in a time of common magic, so he'd have at least some idea of potential supernatural opposition.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a expert on Hellboy, however I have seen the movies and will answer the question based on the that logic.

Also my answer is based that the crown that controls the golden army is not part of the equation.

The army can magically regenerate. With that in mind there only ways I can think of to destroy them would be

1. Disrupt the magic forces that allow them to regenerate.
2. Trap the army and subject them to some force that would be capable of destroying them at a rate faster than they can regenerate (black hole or the sun sound good)
3. Same as 2 above but with a force that would keep destroying them every time they regenerated until the magical force in question would be exhausted.